# Django istartswith utf8 not working

Tags: django

I have this query for case insensitive search:

```
groups = Group.objects.filter.filter(name__istartswith=query)
```

It works fine with English characters. But doesn't work with utf-8 Russian characters(no errors- only case-sensitive search with the same code)
What do I do?

UPD: as a test database I use sqlite. I guess a problem somewhere here.
But may be there is some workaround to this?

Comment: I had the same ptoblem using SQLite (utf-8 Russian), but it works fine with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the [SQLite ICU Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/icu/README.txt):

> SQLite's built-in implementations of these two functions only provide case mapping for the 26 letters used in the English language. The ICU based functions provided by this extension provide case mapping, where defined, for the full range of unicode characters.

> ICU provides two types of case mapping, "general" case mapping and "language specific". Refer to ICU documentation for the differences between the two.

Essentially, you need to make sure you're using a version of SQLite compiled with ICU support to perform case-insensitive collations.